# Currently working on a Python script using AWS Lambda & Cloudwatch to run at a certain time everyday

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm testing one of their expressions "cron(15 10 * * ? *)" to be run at 10:15 UTC everyday, and when I enter it into the cron expression tab I get the following error when trying to create the rule:

```
There was an error while saving rule XXXXXXRule.
Details: Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid..
```

Comment: Your cron expression is correct. From where did you try to create this CloudWatch rule? Is it from the CloudWatch console [1] or from Lambda Console?
[1] https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east-1#rules:action=create

Comment: If you used the CW console, you should only provide the cron expression `15 10 * * ? *`. If you used the Lambda console, you have to provide the `cron(..` part as well `cron(15 10 * * ? *)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the below expression to run the job every day at 10:15.

```
15 10 * * *
```

Below are the details starting from left to right:

```
minute                 0-59
hour                   0-23
day of month           1-31
month                  1-12
day of week            0-7 (0 or 7 is Sunday, or use names; see below)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your cron expression is wrong. Here is the write expression for every day 10:15 execution

```
15 10 * * *
```

Here is the cron expression format description

[image]

Image source : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron